# 301 redirects on a large scale

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am migrating a site and I have 6k+ 301s that I need to sort out.  I have a spreadsheet with the old and new urls and that is as far as I've got.

I don't think putting 6000 lines in .htaccess can be right, what are the alternatives?

Thanks

Comment: Do they have something in common (to build some generic rule) ?

Comment: Are they **all** different ? Maybe you can group some of them in generic rules. Otherwise, you can use `RewriteMap` or put a rule for each redirect